# Is it possible to create an alternative for List in Orchard?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, themes, orchardcms, customization

I just want to customize List view.

is it possible? I think yes. How?

How to name alternative for List of Content types, let say, "Question"

Answer (score 3):

Sure. As the question is a little vague about context, I'll make assumptions. I'll assume that you have a controller action building the list (similar to what the blog is doing). From the action, you are usually building a list shape with code looking something like this:

```
var pager = new Pager(_siteService.GetSiteSettings(), pagerParameters);
var things = _someServiceClass.GetThings(something)
    .Skip(pager.GetStartIndex()).Take(pager.PageSize))
    .Select(p => Shape.Thing_Summary(
        Thing: p,
        SomethingElseThatIsRelevantToTheTemplate: foo));

Shape list = Shape.List(Pager: pager);
list.AddRange(things);
list.Metadata.Alternates.Add("list_things");

return new ShapeResult(this, list);
```

See that line near the end? It's adding the alternate, so that you can build a specific template for that particular list by creating a file named list.things.cshtml in the views folder of your theme.

Comment: An absolutely great tip... you will need that if you have a pager and you want to provide an alternate for a result list without override the pager.

Comment: btw: probaly pager will deserve an alternate: list.Metadata.Alternates.Add("pager");